# How many moves can I make in a single turn in Maharaja?

Tags: maharaja

The [Maharaja](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9440/maharaja-the-game-of-palace-building-in-india) rules state that I can take my two actions any way I like.  I can even sub-divide the actions.  So for example, given the "build palace and house" action, I could build a palace in one city, move my architect to the next city, and then build the house of that same action in the new city.

So far so good.

The question I have is: how many times can I make moves during my turn?  Only once?  More than once?  For example: after taking one action, moving, and taking part of my second action - can I then move a second time to another city and take the remainder of my second action?  If yes, then I could perhaps have visited as many as four cities in one turn (based on two actions, with each action sub-divided).

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the original rules with me, but based on my memory and rules from BGG:

> 7.0 ACTIONS
>
> 7.1 Travelling
>
> Moving an architect is a free action, that does not feature on the action disc. The player may freely move his architect
>   at any time during his turn. He may move his architect to a city,
>   build there and then move him to another city to build there again,
>   and so on.
>
> The only restrictions to moving an architect are: He may never be
>   moved through a village in which no house (of whichever player) is
>   present; He must sometimes pay for his passage.

I would say - **Yes**, you can move as many times as you want, even between your actions (And theoretically *build in **four** different cities, or even **five** with builder special role card* in one turn) as long as you can move to them and pay the passage fee.